# How to dynamically measure and display radius of circle in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to give my user the ability to click on the map and give him a dynamic circle drawing tool which also reads out the radius measurement.  That way the user can see how big the circle he creates is.

For example, something like this :

[image]

Any idea how I can add such a thing to OpenLayers?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20982/how-to-get-the-radius-of-a-circle-in-openlayers

Comment: This does not look like a duplicate to me because I can see no mention of the "persist measure of the radius" requirement in the other Question.

Comment: @PolyGeo is correct - I want to show the radius while the user change the drawn circle size

Comment: Why not provide a text input for the user to directly specify the radius instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this way:

- create a separate layer just for the radii,
- after each feature creation event on circle layer, construct a LINESTRING with two points: the center of the circle as start point and the easternmost vertex as end point, and calculate its length,

  - add this temporary feature to radii layer and label it with its length.

EDIT: I created a sample jsFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/5TQHK/24/. Beware that if you use EPSG:900913, the calculated length will be too distorted to be useful. Use a local coordinate system or geodesic calculations to get meaningful length.

(I know that real circles don't have *vertices*, but in most GIS systems they do :) )

Comment: Very nice , Is there a way to show the radius size while the circle being draw ? like in this example :
http://jorix.github.io/OL-DynamicMeasure/examples/measure-dynamic.html

Comment: Yes, this should be possible as well. To do this you will need to capture the circle geometry at every move. Refer to OpenLayers source code, lib/OpenLayers/Handler/RegularPolygon.js to see how the circle geometry is being constructed and get some idea.