# How to draw a circle in OpenLayers 2 and measure its radius dynamically?

Tags: measurements, dynamic, openlayers-2, geodesic

With OpenLayers 2.13, I want to draw a circle and obtain its radius at each mousemove. The radius would then be returned as arguments of a callback function, for example. But of course, this is not the problem here.

I have tried several ways but none of the worked the way I want:

**METHOD A**

I tried to change the "move" method in OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, adding a custom event in the control of the handler. It worked but, it does not fit my needs, because:

- I can only calculate the "normal" length, and not the "geodesic" length. So, I never get a correct radius.
- By the way, changing the core of OpenLayers doesn't seem very clean to me, nor safe!

**METHOD B**

Using OpenLayers.Control.Measure together with OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeatiure, seemed to be the best option to me. I registered an event for "measurepartial", but it didn't return anything. The "measurepartial" event is not triggered when drawing a circle (RegularPolygon) because there is no point being added (I suppose this is the reason).

**SOURCES**

- In [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83954/how-to-dynamically-measure-and-display-radius-of-circle-in-openlayers?lq=1), it is asked something very similar to what I ask, bt there was no good answer for y case, so I tried to investigate it and post my own question.
- In [this question](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users//2013-January/027296.html), I found the exact same problem as mine, and it is based on this that I applied METHOD A.

**CONCLUSION**

I would rather use something like METHOD B, but I don't know how. The "measurepartial" event is not triggered when using RegularPolygon.

I didn't post code, because it is work-related. And by the way, I think I explained everything that needed to be told.

Comment: Which version of OpenLayers are you using?

Comment: Hi @drunkenwagoner ... I am using OpenLayers 2.13. I am sorry for not having mentioned this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use the move callback:

```
var my_polygonhandler = OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon;

var polygonControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(circles,
my_polygonhandler, {
    handlerOptions: {
        sides: 40
    }
});

polygonControl.handler.callbacks.move = function (e) {

    var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(e.components[0].components);
    var geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]);
    var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, null);
    var polybounds = polygonFeature.geometry.getBounds();

    var minX = polybounds.left;
    var minY = polybounds.bottom;
    var maxX = polybounds.right;
    var maxY = polybounds.top;

    //calculate the center coordinates

    var startX = (minX + maxX) / 2;
    var startY = (minY + maxY) / 2;

    //make two points at center and at the edge
    var startPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(startX, startY);
    var endPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(maxX, startY);
    var radius = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([startPoint, endPoint]);
    var len = Math.round(radius.getLength()).toString();

    document.getElementById("radius").innerHTML = len;


}
```

I just set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate how to use it:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/L529bqb5/

If you want to calculate geodesic length you can use the method "getGeodesicLength" of your linestring.

Comment: Hi @Thomas B. Thank you for your answer. I tried the getGeodesicLength method and it returns approximately 6500 km starting the circle in Washington and ending in London. Of course, the radius would be the distance between the two cities. But, the real geodesic distance between these two is 5900 km, as you can see [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/distanceresult.html%3Fp1=136&p2=263). By the way, in your jsFiddle, you have an [this](http://web-mapping.com/test/RegularPolygon_thomas.js) external resource. Have you modified the RegularPolygon class? Thanks again.

Comment: The external ressource was just from testing. I removed it now. If you want to calculate a grat circle line as done in your example you could have a look at this: http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL26/examples/gc_example.html